# Spark binaryRecords() giving less performance as compare to textFile()

Tags: apache-spark

I have spark job code as below. Which works fine with below configuration on cluster.

```
String path = "/tmp/one.txt";
JavaRDD<SomeClass> jRDD = spark.read()
                            .textFile(path)
                            .javaRDD()
                            .map(line -> {
                                return new SomeClass(line);
                            }); 

Dataset responseSet = sparkSession.createDataFrame(jRDD, SomeClass.class);
responseSet.write()
            .format("text")
            .save(path + "processed");
```

Whereas, If I want to read binary file(same size as text) it takes much more time.

```
String path = "/tmp/one.txt";
JavaRDD<SomeClass> jRDD = sparkContext
                            .binaryRecords(path, 10000, new Configuration())
                            .toJavaRDD()
                            .map(line -> {
                                return new SomeClass(line);
                            }); 

Dataset responseSet = spark.createDataFrame(jRDD, SomeClass.class);
responseSet.write()
            .format("text")
            .save(path + "processed");
```

Below is my configuration.

```
driver-memory 8g
executor-memory 6g
num-executors 16
```

Time taken by first code with 150 MB file is 1.30 mins.
Time taken by second code with 150 MB file is 4 mins.

Also, first code was able to run on all 16 executors whereas second uses only one.

ny suggestions why it is slow?

Comment: Seems like very small file. Can you try with binaryFiles().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The `textFile()`method was creating `16 partitions`(you can check`numOfPartitions` using `getNumPartitions()` method on RDD) whereas `binaryRecords()` created only 1(Java binaryRecords doesn't provide overloaded method which specifies num of partitions to be created).

I increased `numOfPartitions` on RDD created by `binaryRecords()` by using `repartition(NUM_OF_PARTITIONS)` method on RDD.